# The usage of this infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I came across this sentence

> He has been by my side, **my rock and shoulder to lean on** literally, every
>   step of the way, caring for me and Erin, holding my hands, holding me
>   and loving me.

This is from a person's autobiography. I wonder if this sentence "my rock and shoulder to lean on literally" needs a verb like "my rock and shoulder lean on literally". What' the meaning of "to lean on" in this sentence? What's the usage of this infinitive?

Comment: ...my rock and shoulder ***on which to lean***  literally,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case "to lean on" refers to the *purpose*. In other words, the person has been a *shoulder on which I could lean*. This is also an idiomatic phrase meaning *to be an emotional support*, similarly to the phrase [*to be the shoulder to cry on*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_shoulder_to_cry_on). The reference to being somebody's rock comes from [Matthew 16:18](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Matthew-16-18/) where Christ tells Peter:

> That thou art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church

Which finds its reasoning in that "Peter" comes from the Greek *petros*, meaning "rock" (and hence petrification - turning to rock; petroglyphs - rock carvings; petroleum - "rock oil", etc.). Christ is telling Peter that he will be his support and foundation for his work, and this meaning has been adopted by day-to-day language.

With regards to the infinitive structure, other items can be described in a similar way:

- A pen *to write with*
- A wooden board *to chop on*
- A car *to drive in*

And so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is this his shoulder?

Comment: Well, no, he *is* the shoulder. It is an idiomatic phrase. In the same way as someone's shoulder to lean on is helpful when you trip or stumble or are weak, the man was such a support and help when the author's life has been difficult.

Comment: Thanks again. I got it. That is to say, he has been  my rock and shoulder to lean on literally. I misunderstood the subject is my rock and shoulder.